# Best way to create header with text touching top and bottom border

Tags: html, css

I want to create **screen-wide headline with simple text-logo**. Challenge is to make it touching container's top and bottom border [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYct6.png) 
(...as well as it's half-height-variations).

First of all I noticed that in HTML there's a kind of font-build top and bottom margin that prevents top and bottom container's borders from touching text. To fix that i used `line-height` property (with guessing its proper value...).

I ended with this: https://jsfiddle.net/2ukfc8e7/8/

**Is there a better solution?**

Comment: You could use absolute and relative positioning to layer the text on top of the container; however, I suspect there is a better way.

Comment: something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/2ukfc8e7/9/

Comment: Not really - in two last examples i tried to make headline containing upper or bottom half of text (I think it look cool). To make it clear - **basic** question is how to get rid of default text/font top and bottom margin... (it would be great if we could develop best solution for all three examples)

Comment: The only way to get rid of these spaces is using line height, also `float` or `display:block|inline-block` and a fixed height could help. These are not margins, it's the line spacing, that's why you can reduce it with `line-height` and not with `margin`/`padding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there's probably no better solution than my original idea.

Each line of text inside a tag has certain horizontal and vertical space that should not be confused with `margin`/`padding` property. We can define that space using `line-height` property. Decreasing its value we make upper and bottom border bring closer to each other - and - to the line of text.

I made snippet (below) with `line-height` property transition to show described approach (in fancy slow-mo action).

```css
/* RESET */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

p {
  font-weight: normal;
}

header {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 2rem;
  
  /* Irrelevant part */
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
 
  /* Transition stuff*/
  transition-property: line-height;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
header:hover {
  line-height: .67;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:900,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<body>
  <p>Hover header below to see transition from <b>'line-height: 1'</b> to <b>'line-height: 0.67'</b>
  </p>
  <header>ABOF</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div>
  <b>ABOF</b>
</div>
```

Comment: You set `font-size:48px`... Then you shrank `line-height` to `32px`. In last step you set `div`'s `height` also to `32px`. It's basically the same solution I came up with... **Is this the only solution to get rid of default text top and bottom "margin"?**

Comment: @Darek, does it have to be text?

Comment: It was my second thought (rather obvious) but I couldnt find clear answer to my original question and... here we are! :) BTW: THX for contribution!